# No Value for WL-Authentication-Error Exception

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

When using the WLResourceRequest API ,Launching Native Android
application will result in the following exception:

```
WLRequest.java:729 :: No value for WL-Authentication-Failure
    org.json.JSONException: No value for
WL-Authentication-Failure
            at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:389)
```

The application will run normally and the exception only appears
in the log

Worklight Versions Affected:7.0. In ibm support portal, it says its a cosmetic issue and apply the fix for error in the log to go away.

I am not sure what is the "fix for error in the log to go away".  I have the latest fix pack of 7.0 in my server version: 7.0.0.00.20150729-1801.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?crawler=1&uid=swg1PI46002

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have the latest iFix according to the document you have linked to.

It was submitted on August 2nd, but your build is from July 20th.
Find an iFix in IBM Fix Central that is newer than your build. If it's not there, mention this in the comments.

Comment: Hi Idan. Thanks. But the latest fix pack available in Passport Advantage portal is interim fix: 7.0.0.0-MFPF-IF201507291801 which is published on July 31 2015. I am having this version in my server and developer studio. Is this error has some issue with sending client logs to server / analytics? If not i am good and consider this as a cosmetic issue.